# Replace alpha numeric in text using regex/replace in python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I want to remove alphanumeric characters in a text.
For ex I have text as given below:

```
text= I want to remove alphanumeric jhanb562nkk from the text. Remove alphanumeric from all the texts. uhufshfn76429 is very hard to figure out.
```

**Expected result**

```
result=I want to remove alphanumeric from the text. Remove alphanumeric from all the texts.  is very hard to figure out.
```

I am not sure how we can remove them from the text using regex/replace method.

Comment: How about pure numbers? Do you want them removed?

Comment: @Tomothy32, no I don't want to remove pure numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:
`[A-Za-z]+[\d]+[\w]*|[\d]+[A-Za-z]+[\w]*`

The function call would be:
`re.sub(rgx_str, '', text)`

Do note that this would leave a extra space wherever the alphanumeric text was cleared. A simple way to remove this is to run another regex to post-process:
`" +"` and replace with `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear from your question if you need to do it with regex or you'd be happy with any solution. In case you don't have to use regex, here is an answer using list comprehensions:

```
s = 'some con123taminated pure 123 words'
filtered_str = [word for word in s.split() if (all(ch.isdigit() for ch in word) or not any(ch.isdigit() for ch in word))]
filtered_str = ' '.join(filtered_str)
```

I admit it is not easily readable. But the only possibly obscure bit is the `all(.) or not any(.)` part. It basically ensures that either all characters in a word are digits or none of them are.